# Wikimedia CSRF Token invalid

Tags: dart, csrf, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, csrf-token

I am using the [MediaWiki Action API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page), where I use the OAuth2 authorization flow to obtain a access token.

For uploading a image, a CSRF Token is required. I get the token by making a post request to `https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&format=json` with the auth code in the header. This works and I get a response containing the CSRF Token:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "tokens": {
      "csrftoken": "516091e04d05c9ae2c7bca4727c071fb615ee122+\\"
    }
  }
}
```

I then take this token and check for its validity immediately after, making a post request to `https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=checktoken&type=csrf&format=json` with the obtained token in the body (as required per api documentation). These requests happen in less than a second between each other. However, the response always is 'invalid':

```
{
  "checktoken": {
    "result": "invalid",
    "generated": "2021-10-07T12:07:20Z"
  }
}
```

I am using Dart/Flutter btw, but I doubt thats the problem.

Comment: Probably an issue with OAuth authentication? Try `api.php?action=query&meta=userinfo` or `index.php?title=Special:OAuth/identify` (neither of which require a CSRF token) and see if you are recognized.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be formatting the POST body wrong. It should be either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Tgr I am encoding it as www-form-urlencoded and I get recognized by `api.php?action=query&meta=userinfo`, could it be missing permissions?

Comment: I don't think that could result in this error message. Is the `generated` field actually the token generation time? If not, then maybe an encoding error (the slash needs url escaping)? If yes, this sounds like the session gets lost but that shouldn't be possible with OAuth...

Comment: @Tgr I am escaping the slashes and plus, the post body i send to checktoken is `token=9d4f2d7c371bac047d387b46e4f1903f616545e5%2B%5C`. The `generated` is always two hours behind my time, but i figured thats just because of the timezone of the server. Could the token be generated and checked by servers in different timezones?

Comment: No, everything is always in UTC. I can't really think of a possible cause, other than maybe signing one of the requests with the wrong / no OAuth key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long time I finally figured it out, and the answer could not be more simple:

The checktoken action still requires a oAuth 2 access token in the header. With this included, everything works as it should. I hope this at least helps someone else.